# Software to view and add metadata (tags and note) to photos and save it to IPTC

Tags: metadata

Commercial softwares such as Adobe Bridge and Photo Mechanic allows you to easily browse your images and add metadata to them (eg tags and notes). This metadata will be save in the same JPEG file as IPTC metadata.

I am looking for an open-source or freeware software to achieve this, for Mac OSX.

ps: I don't want a software that needs to import all the photos to their folder in order to work.

ps: I am aware of other software (such as Pixa) that saves metadata in OpenMeta, but this metadata is not saved in the same JPEG file and can get lost when copying files to other file system formats. I am not interested in this approach.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line you can use [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) or [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

[Photini](http://photini.readthedocs.org/en/latest/other/introduction.html) is "a free, easy to use, digital photograph metadata (EXIF, IPTC, XMP) editing application." While I don't see a dedicated OS X installation package, as a Python app it is said to be installable by someone with some technical background.

You can either have the metadata imbedded into the image or saved in an external XMP sidecar file. Both these methods are industry standard and in wide use by many image management tools.

A bit off topic, but some background on what metadata one might want to save can be found in the [MWG Guidelines](http://www.metadataworkinggroup.org/pdf/mwg_guidance.pdf).

Comment: i found digikam.org when googling about photini. i'll give that a try.

Comment: digikam.org crashes on my computer and Photini is a pain to install. any other GUI solution?